# Find max and min key in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have associative array like

```
array
{
    [company 1]=>array
                      (
                        [1981] => 1
                        [1945] => 3
                      )
   [company 2]=>array
                    (
                       [1990] => 18
                       [2005] => 13
                    )
   [company 3]=>array
                    (
                       [1950] => 6
                       [2012] => 9
                    )
}
```

I want to get lowest and highest key i.e. 1945 and 2012.
How can i achieve this? I have already searched over stackoverflow and [Hightest value of an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093171/hightest-value-of-an-associative-array)  is the nearest possibility but it gives out min and max value and I want min and max key.

**I don't want to use foreach loop **

Comment: "I don't want to use foreach loop" what's the deal with this arbitrary requirement?

Comment: My resultant array is very large, so it consumes lot of time while recursing and building new array using foreach. Whereas if its possible to do this with min or max functions it would be really beneficial.

Comment: -1 for arbitrary restrictions prohibiting *the very tool made for jobs like this*.  In fact, the requirement brings this question right to the intersection of "too localized" and "not constructive".

Comment: @cHao I thought this can be done using array_keys, min, max, array_map function... I just don't know how.. that's why i asked here.. and i already told my reason to avoid foreach in previous commnet..

Comment: The solution to this question has nothing to do with building a new array even if using foreach. Thus the prohibition is most likely a wrong assumption. Oh by the way, even if using other functions... Do you think there won't be any need for php to loop inside the array without you seeing that?

Comment: @Deadlock: Your reason is invalid.  Any way you do it, you're going to have to loop over the whole array (and each array within, unless you've ksort'ed the sub-arrays).  None of which requires the creation of new arrays.  Fun part, though: if you use `array_keys` or `array_map`, *you're creating a new array anyway*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *really* hate `foreach`, here's a solution:

```php
$arr = array(
  "Company 1" => array(
    "1981" => 1,
    "1945" => 3
  ),

  "Company 2" => array(
    "1990" => 18,
    "2005" => 13
  ),

  "Company 3" => array(
    "1950" => 6,
    "2012" => 9
  )
);


$arr = array_map("array_keys", $arr);
$arr = array_reduce($arr, "array_merge", array());
```

Your `$arr` would end up like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1981
    [1] => 1945
    [2] => 1990
    [3] => 2005
    [4] => 1950
    [5] => 2012
)
```

Now you can use `min()` and `max()` functions or `sort()` it get the highest and lowest value easily.

```
sort($arr);
echo end($arr); /*highest value; actual output: 2012*/
echo reset($arr); /*lowest value; actual output: 1945*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
using foreach.

```
        $array = array("company 1" => array(1981 => 1, 1945 =>3),
                        "company 2" => array(1990 => 18, 2005 => 13),
                        "company 3" => array(1950 => 6, 2012 =>9),
        );

        $keys = array();
        foreach($array as $arr)
        {
            foreach( array_keys($arr) as $val)
            {
                array_push($keys, $val);
            }
        }
        sort($keys);
        $min = $keys[0];
        $max = $keys[count($keys)-1];
```

Without foreach:

```
        global $keys;
        $GLOBALS['keys'] = array();
        function sortme($arr)
        {
            is_array($arr)? array_map("sortme",array_keys($arr)): array_push($GLOBALS['keys'], $arr);

        }
        array_map("sortme",$array);
        sort($GLOBALS['keys']);
        $min = $GLOBALS['keys'][0];
        $max = $GLOBALS['keys'][count($GLOBALS['keys'])-1];
        echo "min = ".$min . "<br/>max = ".$max;
```

Comment: I already mentioned in question that i don't want to use foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
ksort($array);
$min = reset($array);
end($array);
$max = key($array);
```

**EDIT**:
This works for simple array. You have 2 level structure, so it would be close to impossible to avoid looping through it.

However, if you have so many entries that even foreach is too slow, probably you should rethink your approach. For example, put this list into database and use SQL to do heavy lifting for you.

How exactly? Setup instance of MySQL or PostgreSQL (I personally prefer Postgres for many reasons), create database, create table with structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    mytable_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    company VARCHAR(16),
    year INTEGER,
    value INTEGER,
    -- put some more metadata...
)
```

Technically, you should normalize your database and create separate tables for every object (like table for companies, for customers, orders, etc...), but you can come to this later.

Create indexes on columns you are going to be searching on (like year, company, etc):

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_year_idx ON mytable (year);
...
```

Finally, in your PHP script, connect to database and query it for what you wanted, something like this:

```
SELECT min(year) AS min_year,
       max(year) AS max_year
FROM mytable
```

Comment: This works for simple array. You have 2 level structure. You still have to loop over companies, and then for every company entry you can use this procedure to get local min and max

Comment: If you have so many entries that even foreach is too slow, probably you should rethink your approach. For example, put this list into database and use SQL to do heavy lifting for you

Answer (score 0):

**Because** your input array is "*very large*" and "*consumes [a] lot of time*", that is precisely a justification for using a set of simple language constructs to iterate the dataset in a single pass.

Using multiple array functions may look more concise or clever, but they will be making multiple passes over the data and invariably draw more resources than absolutely necessary.

Because your data is dealing with years, you can build business logic into the code logic with "magic numbers" -- assuming that you will never encounter a negative year or a year from 10,000 and beyond.

If you want a more business-agnostic approach, you can seed the default min and max values by shifting the first row off the input array and fetching that subarray's min and max keys.

Magic Number Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ljgqK))

```
$minYear = 9999;
$maxYear = 0;
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $year => $value) {
        if ($year > $maxYear) {
            $maxYear = $year;
        }
        if ($year < $minYear) {
            $minYear = $year;
        }
    }
}
echo "MinYear = $minYear, MaxYear = $maxYear";
// MinYear = 1945, MaxYear = 2012
```

Shifted Defaults Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bKB54))

```
if ($array) {
    $firstKeys = array_keys(array_shift($array));
    $minYear = min($firstKeys);
    $maxYear = max($firstKeys);
} else {
    $minYear = null;
    $maxYear = null;
}
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $year => $value) {
        if ($year > $maxYear) {
            $maxYear = $year;
        } elseif ($year < $minYear) {
            $minYear = $year;
        }
    }
}
echo "MinYear = $minYear, MaxYear = $maxYear";
```

Notice that the Shifted snippet specifically handles the first dataset to get the defaults - which takes a few extra lines - but enjoys higher potential efficiency due to the `elseif`.

Neither of these techniques use iterated function calls, so they are virtually assured to perform faster than functional techniques.