# Finding the largest ID in this PHP associative array

Tags: php

I have a query which returns several thousands objects from my database. The result set is an array of associative arrays. An example would be something along the lines of:

```
Array(
  Array(
     "id" => 500,
     "name" => "Bob"
  ),

  Array(
     "id" => 2,
     "name" => "Cindy"
  ),

  Array(
     "id" => 200,
     "name" => "Jane"
  )
);
```

In this case I'd need to be able to filter/sort this array to retrieve the `id` of `500`.

Comment: if you add a sort order to the querry, then it will be the first (or last)

Comment: a google search can help at times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093171/hightest-value-of-an-associative-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Get the ids into an array (using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php))
2. Get the highest value in the array (using [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php))

This should do the trick:

```
echo max(array_column($array, 'id'));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/449248)

Comment: Also it works with one line using `arsort($array)`, this return the array ordered of inverse way.