# PHP Max() function not working when value hits 10

Tags: php, function, max

So I am having a bit of an issue with this code snippet... Here are my variables:

```
$total_one = ''.$total_one_section.' One'; 
$total_two = ''.$total_two_section.' Two';
$total_three = ''.$total_three_section.' Three';
$highest_total_level = max($total_one,$total_two ,$total_three);
```

The current totals are:

```
10 One
4 Two
3 Three
```

This means that the code should return `10 One` but it is returning `4 Two` for some reason. I have noticed that if I change the value of `One` to `9` so: `9 One` then it returns as it should, `9 One` as the highest. It only seems to stop functioning correctly when the value hits 10? Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: _max() returns the parameter value considered "highest" according to standard comparisons._  You are passing strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, PHP's [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) is an omnivore: it allows arguments of any type, comparing using the [standard comparison rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) with type juggling on demand.

As all the values you passed into it are strings, they are compared on char-by-char basis (so called lexical comparison), starting from the first one. As character `4`'s code point is higher than `1`'s, `'4 Two'` is greater than `'10 One'`.

There are many ways to solve this; the key is storing the original (numeric) values in one way or another. One possible approach is suggested in @Geoffrey's answer - use numbers as key, and their 'tails' as values of this array, then just apply `max` over `array_keys()`:

```
$lines = array(
  '4' => 'Two',
  '3' => 'Three',
  '9' => 'Four',
  '100' => 'One',  
);

$max_key = max(array_keys($lines));
echo $max_key . ' ' . $lines[$max_key]; // 100 One
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings, `4 Two` starts with `4` while `10 One` starts with `1`. That's what `MAX` is comparing. You should compare `$total_two_section`, `$total_one_section` and `$total_three_section`, since they are integers.

Answer (score 0):

What PHP is trying to do is to sort your number as string, you might prefer something like :

```
$numbers = array(

  10 => "one",
  4 => "two",
  3 => "three"

)
```

Then mix with something like that [Hightest value of an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093171/hightest-value-of-an-associative-array)